# Why findRandom() mongoose for node.js method doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Schema:

```
var random = require('mongoose-random');

var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(...)
productSchema.plugin(random, {path: 'r'});

var products = mongoose.model('sportsStore', productSchema);
module.exports = products;
```

Calling findRandom(), console displays "[]"

```
getRandomProducts: function (count) {
    products.findRandom().limit(count).exec(function(error, result) {
        console.log(result);  // -> []
    })
```

Method find() works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And probably solution could be here - see the comments on [npm page mongoose-random](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-random) example .

```
// if you have an existing collection, it must first by synced.
// this will add random data for the `path` key for each doc.
```

Try

```
productSchema.syncRandom(function (err, result) {
   console.log(result.updated);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the line

```
productSchema.plugin(random, {path: 'r'});
```

To

```
productSchema.plugin(random());
```

Wasn't tested, but should work.