# mongoose-random response 500

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I've just opened a `nodeJS` code trying to get random documents from my `mongoose` collection using [mongoose-random](https://github.com/matomesc/mongoose-random), but for any reason when I call to `findRandom()` method, it responses a `500`.

**test.js**

Here bellow I paste my code:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var random       = require('mongoose-random');
var Promise      = require('bluebird');

mongoose.Promise = Promise;

var TestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
});

TestSchema.plugin(random, {path: 'r'});

TestSchema.statics = {
  start: function (value) {
    var array = [], i = 1;
    for (i; i < value; i += 1) {
      array.push({ _id: i });
    }
    return this.create(array);
  },
  getRandom: function () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      TestSchema.findRandom().limit(10).exec(function (err, songs) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else { 
          resolve(songs);
        }
      });
    });
  }
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('TestSchema', TestSchema);
```

**routes.js**

```
var router        = require('express').Router();
var path          = require('path');
var Promise       = require('bluebird');
var request       = require('request');

var test   = require('./models/test.js');

router.get('/fill', function (req, res) {
  test.start(40)
    .then(function () {
      res.status(200).send('You can start your hack :)');
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      res.status(400).send(error);
    });
});

router.get('/vote', function (req, res) {
  test.getRandom()
    .then(function (data) {
      res.status(200).send(data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      res.status(400).send(error);
    }); 
});

module.exports = router;
```

Reading other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689543/why-findrandom-mongoose-for-node-js-method-doesnt-work) as a solution purposes to use `syncRandom()` method, but that doesn't work for me. Neither using `random()`

Any help? Thanks in advice.

**UPDATE**

Digging more into the issue, I've realiced my model `TestSchema`, which should contain `mongoose-random` methods is being overrided, so I only have my statics methods.

Comment: Your issue isn't mongoose. `this` within the promise of `getRandom` doesn't refer to the model, it refers to the function within `new Promise`. Within that context, `findRandom` is undefined.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was a mistake of mine when I edited the last time.

Comment: If your MongoDB server is at least 3.2, you're probably better off using the built-in [`$sample`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#pipe._S_sample) pipeline operator.

Comment: The problem is on the `Schema` which doesn't contain the method `getRandom`, which was overrided when setting mines: `TestSchema.statics = { // **** // }` @cdbajorin

Comment: Don't set `statics` to a new object, just add methods to it. `TestSchema.statics.start = function(value) ...`

Comment: @JohnnyHK your answer was perfect for what I was looking for, thanks!. I'm new with all this stuff, so I understood as well adding methods to the static `object` instead of creating a new one, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set `statics` to a new object, just add methods to it:

```
TestSchema.statics.start = function (value) {
    var array = [], i = 1;
    for (i; i < value; i += 1) {
      array.push({ _id: i });
    }
    return this.create(array);
  };

TestSchema.statics.getRandom = function () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      TestSchema.findRandom().limit(10).exec(function (err, songs) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else { 
          resolve(songs);
        }
      });
    });
  };
```

However, if your MongoDB server is at least 3.2, you're probably better off using the built-in [`$sample`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#pipe._S_sample) pipeline operator instead of a plugin to select random documents.

```
test.aggregate([{$sample: 10}], callback);
```